# Marketing Cloud Email not sending to expected recipients

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email, custom-reports

I'm really new to SFMC and I am struggling to understand something.

I moved over 500000 subscribers into a Data Extension using Email|Interactions|Import from a Salesforce report.

I then scheduled an email to them over the weekend and throttled to about 500 per.

I logged in this morning and only 72 emails sent. What am I missing? I did add the opt-outs and unsubscribers to the suppression list but that only amounts to about 1% of the total list.

I sent the email using Email|Content|{item}|Send and selecting my audience from the DE and adding global exclude (our name for all of the people to whom we don't send.

Comment: May be try reaching out to SF Support?'

Comment: Have a look at Email Studio -> Tracking -> Sends and share the information you can find there.

Comment: @DonLYes - It showed only 72.